# Merging keys in concourse YAML files

Tags: yaml, concourse

How can I merge keys in concourse? My var file has key value pairs like

```
cf-api-app: api-
cf-dispatcher-app: dispatcher-
cf-space: test
```

In my pipeline I want to pass param to my task which should look something like

```
PCF_API_APP_NAME: ((cf-api-app))-((cf-space))
PCF_DISPATCHER_APP_NAME: ((cf-dispatcher-app))-((cf-space))
```

So my task can get a param based on environment, and it would look something like

```
PCF_API_APP_NAME: api-test
PCF_DISPATCHER_APP_NAME: dispatcher-test
```

But I guess somehow, it does not take the combination as expected and is unable to evaluate it.

I even tried using anchor in my `config.yml` so that I can merge keys in the config file instead of pipeline but still it does not work.

```
aliases: &environ test

cf-api-app: api-*environ (fails)
cf-dispatcher-app: dispatcher-*environ (fails)
cf-space: *environ (works)
```

Comment: YAML anchors and aliases work on nodes, not on (substrings of) string scalars. That feature is described [here](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2765878). Therefore `api-*environ` is just a scalar with a `*` in the middle. For what you want to do, you need some template preprocessing.

Comment: What is the error you are getting with `(())`?

Comment: That link was useful, I understood about the aliases. I guess the overall problem was with concourse version. We are using 2.6 and the interpolation is supported in version 3.2 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

The following alias mapping fails in concourse.

```
  aliases: &environ test

  cf-api-app: api-*environ (fails)
  cf-dispatcher-app: dispatcher-*environ (fails)
```

### Solution

- This is contingent on the concourse version.
- This is supported in concourse version 3.2+

### Pitfalls

- This kind of alias mapping is a part of concourse and is not a part of the native YAML specification.